# Material design fixed tabs under toolbar

Tags: android, tabs, material-design

What is the best way to implement and design (color for background / selected : Unselected...) fixed tabs in material design such as fixed tabs of the youtube application ?

[image: Youtube tabs example]

I have currently a toolbar and fixed tabs under the toolbar but there is a difference of elevation. So I guess I am doing something wrong.

[image: My tab test]

I am also really interesting on any advice regarding the changes of the fixed tab design such as color, text color...

Answer (score 1):

There is a library that might help you with this. It's on Github so if you want you can dive into the code as well. Check it out here: https://github.com/neokree/MaterialTabs

Answer (score 1):

You can use ViewPager and some other files from Google's open source I/O Schedule app to make fixed sliding tabs with Material Design. I have made a tutorial on Sliding tabs with Material Design and the result i got is tabs like this:

[image]

Here is the link to the tutorial: 
[Android Sliding Tabs With Material Design](http://www.exoguru.com/android/material-design/navigation/android-sliding-tabs-with-material-design.html) :D

Comment: Hi, i am using your tutorial, check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30184985/sliding-tabs-in-toolbar-using-material-design