# Sliding Tabs in Toolbar using Material Design

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, android-tabs

I have been learning to use Sliding Tabs using Material Design using [this post](http://www.exoguru.com/android/material-design/navigation/android-sliding-tabs-with-material-design.html). I have managed to achieve SlidingTabs **below** the `Toolbar`, like this one:

[image]

But now i would like to create **ActionBar/ToolBar Fragment Tabs** ...

Comment: here you can found a nice example: http://www.android4devs.com/2015/01/how-to-make-material-design-sliding-tabs.html

Comment: like i wrote i am already done with Sliding Tabs below Toolbar

Comment: `Sliding Tabs below Toolbar` means ? post the image which you want to achieve!!!

Comment: You're trying to achieve Navigation tab like Practo app but that is not with toolbar + tab(material design) but it is ActionBar(deprecated in v21) + tabs(with old theme). Check my both exampl : http://github.com/dhaval0122/ActionBar-Navigation-Tabs

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was able to recreate exactly what you are looking to implement. I am using the this [Library](https://github.com/jpardogo/PagerSlidingTabStrip) for the tabs.

**This is the view I have created:**

[image]

**Import Library Through Dependencies or Download Project and Import Manually**

```
compile 'com.jpardogo.materialtabstrip:library:1.0.9'
```

**styles.xml**

```
<resources>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

**MainActivity & Adapter**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    Toolbar toolbar;
    ViewPager viewPager;
    ContactPagerAdapter pagerAdapter;
    PagerSlidingTabStrip pagerSlidingTabStrip;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        toolbar.setLogo(R.mipmap.logo_two);
        toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu_main);
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        pagerAdapter = new ContactPagerAdapter(this, getSupportFragmentManager());
        pagerSlidingTabStrip = (PagerSlidingTabStrip) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
        pagerSlidingTabStrip.setViewPager(viewPager);
    }

    public static class ContactPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter implements PagerSlidingTabStrip.CustomTabProvider {

        private final int[] ICONS = {R.mipmap.ic_launcher, R.mipmap.ic_launcher};
        Context mContext;
        private Fragment f = null;

        public ContactPagerAdapter(Context ctx, FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
            mContext = ctx;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return ICONS.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) { // Returns Fragment based on position
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    f = new FragmentPageOne();
                    break;
                case 1:
                    f = new FragmentPageTwo();
                    break;
            }
            return f;
        }

        @Override
        public View getCustomTabView(ViewGroup parent, int position) {
            LinearLayout customLayout = (LinearLayout) LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, parent, false);
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) customLayout.findViewById(R.id.image);
            imageView.setImageResource(ICONS[position]);
            return customLayout;
        }
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#02a6d8"
        android:minHeight="56dp"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <com.astuetz.PagerSlidingTabStrip
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="56dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:background="#02a6d8"
            app:pstsDividerColor="#02a6d8"
            app:pstsIndicatorColor="#fff"
            app:pstsIndicatorHeight="2dp"
            app:pstsShouldExpand="false"
            app:pstsUnderlineHeight="0dp"/>
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"/>

    <!-- Shadow below toolbar-->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="5dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        android:background="@drawable/toolbar_shadow"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**custom_tab.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Drawrable toolbar_shadow.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <gradient
        android:angle="270"
        android:endColor="@android:color/transparent"
        android:startColor="@color/semi_transparent"/>
</shape>
```

Answer (score 1):

In fact the tabs are not in the toolbar. The toolbar is just hidden. You can hide the toolbar calling `getSupportActionBar().hide()` and the toolbar will be gone. As a result of this the tabs will be at the top of the screen.

Comment: I am not sure I understand you right... May you explain in more depth what do you mean by saying **Sliding Tabs in ToolBar**

Comment: @KirilAleksandrov `This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question. It should possibly be an edit, a comment, another question, or deleted altogether.`

Answer (score 1):

As i already wrote you can find an example here: http://www.android4devs.com/2015/01/how-to-make-material-design-sliding-tabs.html

By the way, what you need to is include in your project this code: https://developer.android.com/samples/SlidingTabsColors/src/com.example.android.common/view/SlidingTabLayout.html. So create a class in which you will paste the entire code.

Then create your activity that extends `ActionBarActivity` like for example this one:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

static final String LOG_TAG = "SlidingTabsBasicFragment";
private SlidingTabLayout mSlidingTabLayout;
private ViewPager mViewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_sample);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_awesome_toolbar);

    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(new SamplePagerAdapter());
    mSlidingTabLayout = (SlidingTabLayout) findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs);
    mSlidingTabLayout.setViewPager(mViewPager);

    /*
     * FragmentTransaction transaction =
     * getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
     * SlidingTabsBasicFragment fragment = new SlidingTabsBasicFragment();
     * transaction.replace(R.id.sample_content_fragment, fragment);
     * transaction.commit();
     */

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

class SamplePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    /**
     * @return the number of pages to display
     */
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 5;
    }

    /**
     * @return true if the value returned from
     *         {@link #instantiateItem(ViewGroup, int)} is the same object
     *         as the {@link View} added to the {@link ViewPager}.
     */
    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object o) {
        return o == view;
    }

    // BEGIN_INCLUDE (pageradapter_getpagetitle)
    /**
     * Return the title of the item at {@code position}. This is important
     * as what this method returns is what is displayed in the
     * {@link SlidingTabLayout}.
     * <p>
     * Here we construct one using the position value, but for real
     * application the title should refer to the item's contents.
     */
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return "Item " + (position + 1);
    }

    // END_INCLUDE (pageradapter_getpagetitle)

    /**
     * Instantiate the {@link View} which should be displayed at
     * {@code position}. Here we inflate a layout from the apps resources
     * and then change the text view to signify the position.
     */
    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        // Inflate a new layout from our resources

        View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.pager_item,
                container, false);
        // Add the newly created View to the ViewPager
        container.addView(view);

        // Retrieve a TextView from the inflated View, and update it's text
        TextView title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_title);
        title.setText(String.valueOf(position + 1));

        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "instantiateItem() [position: " + position + "]");

        // Return the View
        return view;
    }

    /**
     * Destroy the item from the {@link ViewPager}. In our case this is
     * simply removing the {@link View}.
     */
    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        container.removeView((View) object);
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "destroyItem() [position: " + position + "]");
    }

}
```

of course this fragment layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/my_awesome_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"

        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <com.example.android.common.view.SlidingTabLayout
                android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0px"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/white" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and the pager_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:gravity="center">

    <TextView
          android:id="@+id/item_subtitle"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
          android:text="Page:"/>

    <TextView
          android:id="@+id/item_title"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:textSize="80sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

This is the way to do it.

You can also use this library: https://github.com/florent37/MaterialViewPager or this one: https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/1100

Comment: check now i have posted screenshot.. what i would like to achieve ?

Comment: Using my code you can do it. you need to create a layout like yours. But to use the ViewPager with toolbar you need to do what i wrote.